# How to get value from merged-cells in Excel document using OpenXML and C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have problem with merged cells. If I have value in first cell (B3) and this cell is merged with some others cells (for example C3, D3, E3, F3, F4) - in Excel document I can see only one value. This is great, but I would like to get from my GetCellValue function the same B3 value, when I ask for C3, D3, E3, F3 value.

I suppose it is necessary to find all merged cells list and read value from the first one - but how to do this using OpenXml?

```
    public string GetCellValue(char ch, int y)
    {
        WorksheetPart wsPart = GetWorksheetPart(_sheetName);
        var addressName = new StringValue(ch + "" + y);

        Cell cell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
            Where(c => c.CellReference.Value == addressName).FirstOrDefault();

        if (cell == null)
            return null;

        return cell.InnerText;
    }
```

UPDATE:

I have found partial solution (finding merged column names in OpenXML):

```
        List<MergeCells> mergeCells;
        WorksheetPart wsPart = GetWorksheetPart(_sheetName);
        if (wsPart.Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().Count() > 0)
        {
            mergeCells = wsPart.Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().ToList();
            string cells = mergeCells[0].OuterXml;
        }
```

Comment: `cell.MergeArea` should give you the cell object for B3, even if cell is C3. (At least that's what the object model allows in VBA, not sure about c# as with last question ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

```
if (wsPart.Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().Count() > 0)
{
     MergeCells mergeCells = wsPart.Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>().First();
     foreach (MergeCell mergeCell in mergeCells)
     {
         // mergeCell.
     }
}
```

Comment: How can I ger merged cell count? For example if A3:D3 merged cells, merged count should be 4 (A3,B3,C3,D3)