# Openxml excel c# does the row has merged cells

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a spreadsheet which has two rows with three columns,

```
--------------------------------------
| title | id | roles 
------------------------------------------
| DOC   | 1  | pediatrician
-----------------------------------------
| NURSE | 2  | A&E
|       |    | pediatrics
|       |    | orthopedic
-----------------------------------------
| DOC   | 3  | orthopedic
-----------------------------------------
```

**In which row 2 (NURSE ) column 3 (roles) have a merged cell**

using C# (openxml) I want to read  column (roles) as one single values

can some one help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value from merged-cells in Excel document using OpenXML and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069399/how-to-get-value-from-merged-cells-in-excel-document-using-openxml-and-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks but No. I want to read rows 1, 2 and 3. but when it comes to row 2 I want to make sure that I read all the data from [roles]

Comment: Using `Worksheet.Elements<MergeCells>()` like in the linked question will allow you to do that.